# Есть ли смысл сжимать поток TCP данных (lz4 compression)

Tags: tcp, сжатие

Собственно, есть постоянные данные, которые отправляются и присылаются с игрового клиента на сервер. 
Максимальный размер данных 8192 байта, который может быть разом передан от клиента к серверу и наоборот. На практике, данные редко бывают размером более 1000 байт, только если я делаю сериализацию, то может получиться 1200-1600 байт данных, но в 90% случаях данные не превышают 64-560 байт.

Собственно, стоит ли овчинка выделки? Я так понимаю, при таких размерах данных вообще нет смысла использовать какой либо алгоритм сжатия данных так как я потеряю только время на методы сжатия и декомпрессии данных или я ошибаюсь?

p.s. поверх потока данных еще используется AES-256

Comment: применять или не применять сжатие зависит только от содержимого потока данных. если поток потенциально может быть сжат и это стоит затрат процессорного времени на это - то его надо сжать. в противном случае - не надо. если поток потенциально не сжимаем, то от сжатия он только увеличится. Так что вопрос в том как именно выглядят передаваемые данные. И в любом случае шифрование надо накладывать поверх сжатия. уже шифрованные данные сжать невозможно

Comment: зависит от данных, если там одни нули, а обмен идёт с полярной станцией через DialUp, то выигрыш наверняка будет существенный, а если там вывод `/dev/urandom`, который передаётся через 10G сеть, то само собой бессмысленно... в общем попробуй с'dump'и несколько сотен реальных пакетов, сожми и оцени разницу — ради 15% можно и заморочится, если меньше — ИМХО нет... само собой сжимать нужно не шифрованные данные...

Comment: пока данные не превышают 1460 байт сжимать их действительно нет смысла. потому что они влезают в один ethernet кадр. передача одного кадра практически одинакова по времени, вне зависимости от объема данных в нем. Но если вы например работаете на модеме со скоростью 1200 бод то любое сжатие будет полезно

Comment: @Mike, а можно какие-то объяснения/пруфы, на контринтуитивное «передача одного кадра практически одинакова по времени, вне зависимости от объема данных в нем»?

Comment: @Mike, тогда, если вы правы, то я могу использовать сжатия и не использовать его одновременно, например. Я могу проверять размер данных и если size > 1460, то используем lz4 сжатие и в заголовок сжатых данных добавляем специальную сигнатуру, а на клиенте проверяем, если сигнатура присутствует - распаковываем данные и обрабатываем их... Если размер данных меньше 1460, то не испольузем lz4, а передаем как есть

Comment: @Fat-Zer Я не изучал глубоко особенностей работы ethernet. Но я: 1. очень часто сталкивался с инструкциями с сетевому оборудованию. Скорость работы любого оборудования измеряется в PPS (Packet per second). 2. я отлично помню историю 10 летней давности, когда разработчики torrent додумались передавать данные мелкими udp пакетами и почти убили интернет. провайдерам пришлось массово менять маршрутизаторы, их процессоры не справлялись с маршрутизацией огромного кол-ва мелких пакетов. Кстати вот и ответ - время маршрутизации зависит в первую очередь от поиска в таблице маршрутизации

Comment: @Дан Размер кадра, он же MTU может быть разным. пакет где то на маршруте к получателю может пройти через какую нибудь среду физическую или программную в которой MTU окажется ниже стандартных 1500 байт. так что сжимать возможно стоит начиная с 1000, что бы наверняка. ну и действительно стоит провести эксперимент на том протоколе в котором у вас будут передаваться данные, посмотреть на сколько они сжимаемы

Comment: @Mike, ясно, спасибо, я бы сказал, что время передачи здесь скорее зависит от того, где узкое место — или общей пропускной способности канала от клиента до сервера, или в линии передачи, или в загруженности оборудования на пути...

Comment: @Mike, вот нашел статью на хабре
https://habr.com/ru/post/226807/
Вы были правы, на TCP выделяется 1460 байт MSS

Comment: @Mike, кстати, а почему MTU незаметен, когда я передаю данные от сервера к клиенту и наоборот? Имею в виду, пакет если я шлю размером 2000 байт к прмеру, то на клиент 2000 байт и доходит, значит ли это что у меня MTU выше 1500 или же я не понимаю как это устроено? 

Или же это не так работает, а мой пакет от сервера к провайдеру поступает кусками по 1500 байт, а потом уже целый пакет летит на клиент?

Comment: на клиент не может лететь 2000 байт, его сетевая карта этого не поймет. TCP для того и придуман, что бы передавать данные и не задумываться, как оно на канальном уровне устроено. Он разбивает данные при передаче как ему хочется. Дополнительно IP может фрагментировать свои пакеты на маршруте если они где то не пролезают из за уменьшения MTU на каком то участке. В итоге это все собирается обратно в поток. В завершении передаваемого блока данных передачик выставляет флаг PSH, по которому принимающая сторона проталкивает данные клиенту.

Comment: И кстати TCP не гарантирует, что при передаче 2000 байт принимающее приложение получит ровно одно сообщение от ядра, включающее все 2000 байт. Это же поток. Ядро вполне может вас вызывать и говорить что пришел 1 байт и так 2000 раз. А может и по приходу 2000 не отдать их сразу, а подождать какое то время, вдруг еще данные придут. И если они придут отдать вам скажем 2100 байт. Из которых 100 будут уже из следующей передачи. И ваша программа в любом случае должна быть готова работать с такими данными ...